# Get all the TR with exactly 4 TD children

Tags: xml, xpath

How to write the xpath to get all the `tr`s with exactly four child `td`s?

```
<table>
 <tr>
   <td>item</td>
   <td><a>...</a></td>
   <td>item2</td>
   <td>item3</td>
   <td>item4</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>....</td>
   <td>....</td>
   <td><a>....</a></td>
   <td>....</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `count()` (at least with MS XML):

```
//table/tr[count(*) = 4]
```